# Nginx waits until the request ends for the receipt of cookies

Tags: php, nginx

Nginx waits until the request ends for the receipt of cookies, How to get the cookie when it is generated through php without waiting for the end of the request?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using nginx version 1.5.6+, you can use set [`fastcgi_buffering`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_buffering) directive to 'off', or do something like

```
<?php
header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
```

to achieve the same effect. Please note that PHP won't flush the headers (which contains the cookies) unless there's some output to send in the body (using `echo` or `print`). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/1856239) for more info on headers.